# How to send action plan to followupboss using rest api in php

Tags: php, json, rest, api

I'm trying to send leads and inquiry to followupboss crm, this is the php code i used for connecting to the followupboss rest API https://github.com/FollowUpBoss/fub-api-examples

everything is working correctly, Now I have to add action plan json field to the code. but it is not working,

this is my code:

```
$data = array(
"source" => $propertyname . "-Landing page",
"type" => "Property Inquiry",
"pageTitle" => $propertyname,
"pageUrl" => $prpurl,
"pageDuration" => "",
"message" => "Viewed: " . $propertyname,
"person" => array( 
    "firstName" => $fname ,
    "lastName" => $lname ,
    "emails" => array(array("value" => $email)),
    "phones" => array(array("value" => $phone)),
    "assignedTo" => "Hossein Shahi",
    "addresses" => array(
    // Address 1
    array(
         "street" => "322 S Broadway"
    )
    // If there are more than 1 address, add here
    ,array(
         "street" => "" 
    )
),
    "tags" => array(),  
),      
"property" => array(
    "street" => $propertyname,
    "city" => "",
    "state" => "",
    "code" => "",
    "mlsNumber" => $mlscnm,
    "price" => $prpprice,
    "forRent" => false,
    "url" => $prpurl,
    "type" => $prptype,
    "bedrooms" => $prpbeds,
    "bathrooms" => $prpbaths,
    "area" => $prparea,
    "lot" => 0
),
    "actionPlans" => array(
    "status" => "Active",
    "name" => "Buyer - Pre Construction",
    "id" => ""
)
);
```

Comment: Please add more information about what kind of error you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actionPlans` isn't a valid field for new leads created via the `/events` API. That's why it's not working.

Action plans [created in the UI](https://help.followupboss.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014150254-How-to-Create-and-Edit-Action-Plans) are automatically triggered when a new lead comes in. Use the app to associate an action plan with an assignee. That is how you ensure an action plan will be in effect for a lead and the person handling it.

Alternatively, you can make a second API call to [`/actionPlansPeople`](https://docs.followupboss.com/reference#action-plans-people-post) to enable an action plan for a specific assignee. New items assigned to that user will use the action plan.